# Create matrix from categorical columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Suppose I have the following data:

```
customer_id product_1 product_2 product_3
a           1         0         1
b           0         0         1
c           1         1         0
```

Where 0/1 denotes whether a particular customer purchased the product in its respective column. I need to restructure this into the format:

```
customer_count product_1 product_2 product_3
product_1      0         1         1
product_2      1         0         0
product_3      1         0         0
```

Where the count is the number of customers that purchased a particular combination (irrespective of order).

Is this possible? If so, what's the array formula I need for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one formula which can do it for you:

`=IF(B$7=$A8,0,SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,0,MATCH($A8,$B$1:$D$1,0)),INDEX($B$2:$D$4,0,MATCH(B$7,$B$1:$D$1,0))))`

- `INDEX(..MATCH` expressions selects the columns according to first column / header product
  (`0` parameter of `INDEX` selects the whole row / column)
- `SUMPRODUCT` combines the two arrays

[image]